# Como modifico los registros que tienen fecha vacía y ponerles diferentes hora a cada uno

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema que cuando quiero actualizar los registros que tienen la columna fecha_ingreso vacía, a la hora de modificar su fecha todos los registros que quiero modificar se le pone la misma fecha pero yo no quiero que tengan exactamente los mismos segundos todos los registros.

Esta fue mi prueba

```
DECLARE @QUERYUPDATE NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ESQUEMA VARCHAR(50) = 'dbo';
DECLARE @TABLA VARCHAR(50) = 'PRODREL';
DECLARE @miQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @QUERYUPDATE = '
   DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME2(0) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 20);
UPDATE
   '+@ESQUEMA+'.BK_'+@TABLA+' 
SET
   FECHA_INGRESO = DATEADD(SS, 1, @FECHA) 
WHERE
   FECHA_INGRESO = '''+'''';

SELECT
   @miQuery = @QUERYUPDATE;
IF OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(@ESQUEMA, '.BK_', @TABLA)) IS NOT NULL 
EXEC sp_executesql @miQuery;
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo quiero tener este resultado de las fechas con diferencia de segundos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar row_number para numerar las filas y de esta numeración extraes el número de segundos a añadir.

```
drop table if exists dbo.M1;

Create table dbo.M1
             (
             id            int
           , FECHA_INGRESO varchar(30)
             );
go

Insert into dbo.M1(id
                 , Fecha_ingreso)
values
       ( 1, Convert(VARCHAR(30), GetDate(), 20) ),
       ( 2, '' ),
       ( 3, Convert(VARCHAR(30), GetDate(), 20) ),
       ( 4, '' ),
       ( 5, '' );
```

[image: Res1]

Ahora con la estructura montada.

```
DECLARE @QUERYUPDATE NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ESQUEMA VARCHAR(50) = 'dbo';
DECLARE @TABLA VARCHAR(50) = 'M1';
DECLARE @miQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @QUERYUPDATE = N'
DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME2(0) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 20);
With cte as (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null)) AS RN
    From '+@ESQUEMA+N'.'+@TABLA+N'
    WHERE FECHA_INGRESO = ''''
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Fecha_ingreso = DATEADD(SS,RN,@FECHA);
';


SELECT
   @miQuery = @QUERYUPDATE;
IF OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(@ESQUEMA, '.', @TABLA)) IS NOT NULL 
EXEC sp_executesql @miQuery;
```

[image: Res2]

Como puedes observar he cambiado el sufijo que tenías a las tablas por mi ejemplo. Pero la estructura es la misma. El código sin ser dinámico es así:

```
DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME2(0) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 20);
With cte as (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null)) AS RN
    From dbo.M1 
    WHERE FECHA_INGRESO = ''
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Fecha_ingreso = DATEADD(SS,RN,@FECHA);
```

En la [cte](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/) haces un [row_number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/) sobre las filas que tengan `Fecha_Ingreso` como '' y luego en la update directamente sobre el `cte`, aplicas la función `dateAdd`, pero en vez de sumar 1 segundo, sumas la numeración.